# Acrobat Javascript to update embedded jpeg exif data

Tags: pdf, jpeg, exif, acrobat

I wish to use pdf form fields to update exif data to an image in the form.  Is this possible with Acrobat's javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Without additional help, this is not possible. Acrobat JavaScript has no access to files other than PDF files.

If the image has been imported as PDF, you might be able to (if it not already is) turn it into a Data Object, and you might be able to access that Data Object's metadata.

You would be able to access an image's metadata by using a custom plug-in; you might have to use an extra field for carrying over the metadata to Acrobat JavaScript.